# Mixing Eithers and other exceptions inside an either.eager

Tags: arrow-kt

I have code I've written inside an either.eager

```
return either.eager<MyException, MyResponse> {

    val objList = service.getObjs().bind()
    val obj = objList.find{...} ?: throw MyException.notFoundException()

    someOtherService.doSomethingWith(obj).bind()
}
.fold(
    ...
)
```

My question is:

Is this the idiomatic way to handle errors within an either.eager? i.e is it ok to throw an exception from inside an eager?

I could create a function to do the `find` and return an `Either` there but that isn't exactly the kotlin idiomatic way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each EffectScope and EagerEffectScope expose `shift`, where you can short-circuit to `R` in this case `MyException`.

When `find` returns a Nullable Type you can use `ensureNotNull`, which uses `shift` underneath.

```kotlin
return either.eager<MyException, MyResponse> {

    val objList = service.getObjs().bind()
    val obj = ensureNotNull(objList.find{...}) { MyException.notFoundException() }

    someOtherService.doSomethingWith(obj).bind()
}
.fold(
    ...
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer Imran. I tried this, but I get a `estricted suspending functions can only invoke member or extension suspending functions on their restricted coroutine scope`

Also, more generally speaking, what if I wanted to short circuit for some other reason, not specifically notNull?

Comment: That means one of the functions above is suspended and you would need `either<MyException, MyResponse>`, instead of `either.eager`. Short circuiting always works with `shift`[here](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow/blob/d5edbe2fc337d50ae83a9a60a197f21fdeb5c93c/arrow-libs/core/arrow-core/src/commonMain/kotlin/arrow/core/continuations/EagerEffectScope.kt#L33) or [here](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow/blob/d5edbe2fc337d50ae83a9a60a197f21fdeb5c93c/arrow-libs/core/arrow-core/src/commonMain/kotlin/arrow/core/continuations/EffectScope.kt#L31), unless I misunderstood your last question.

Comment: Arrow core continuations works with the suspension system in Kotlin, that means an EffectScope allows both suspended and non-suspended computations, but EagerEffectScope prohibits suspended functions. That's why you're getting the same compiler error message as if you would run a suspended function in non suspended context.

Comment: Thank you Imran. I think I need to upgrade my arrow to get this to work. I'm on 1.1.3 now and its working fine. 

While the ensureNotNull is a nice way to handle this, is there another more generic way to handle this?

Comment: Ignore my last comment. I found the docs and it explains clearly that ensure (and ensureNOtNull) do or do not allow the binding to continue. 

https://arrow-kt.io/docs/apidocs/arrow-core/arrow.core.computations/-either-effect/ensure.html

I think this is the nice generic way I was looking for. Thank you again.